# Laravel 4 using query builder for LEFT() mysql string function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm wondering how to create a LEFT() string function using Laravel's query builder. This is what I'm going for and what returns the correct results for me.

MySQL version

```
SELECT id, title, LEFT(body, 141) AS body FROM posts
```

---

attempt at query builder

```
$posts = Post::select('title', 'id', DB::raw('left("body", 141)'))->orderBy('created_at')->get(3);
```

I don't revieve any errors and I can use `{{ $post->title }}`, but when I try to use the `{{ $post->body }}` then I see nothing.

Comment: You didn't alias your left function to `body` in the query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no need to answer the question but regarding the situation here, you are trying an excerpt like content from a field, which means you want to grab only `141` characters from `body` field and while this would work but you have to tweak it because `LEFT` function would return exactly `141` characters and it could be ended up (the last character) in the middle of a word like `hel...` where the word is `hello` and `141th` character is `l` so it needs to be a complete word to show an excerpt and `Laravel` has built-in solution for this, using `Str::words()` method you can specify how many complete words to show so I think, you may use this as well:

```
Str::words($post->body, 30); // show first 30 words from the $post->body
```

Default is:  `words($value, $words = 100, $end = '...')`

```
Str::words($post->body)
```

This will output, first `100` complete words from any text and it'll end with `...`, so, for example, if the `hello` is the last word then it'll ended like `hello...`.